# Select2 in Sweet Alert 2?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2, sweetalert2

I would like to make a multiple input popup with [Sweet Alert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io), and one of these input fields should be a select with multiple choices . I tried select2 multiple in some pages like in this example:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">  
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
 ...<option value="WY">Wyoming</option> 
</select>
```

With the plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2(); 
});
```

I tried to insert the HTML code in the custom html description of sweet alert configuration, but it has no effect. It is possibile to insert a select2 in a [swal2](https://sweetalert2.github.io)? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Ok, in fact it is possibile, I used the swal2 method `onOpen`, and I loaded there the select2 plugin, using my custom html code:

```
                   swal({
                    title: "Messaggio",
                    html: html,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#26C281',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Salva',
                    confirmButtonColor: '#26C281',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    cancelButtonText: 'Chiudi',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#EF4836',
                    focusConfirm: false,
                    onOpen: function () {
                        $('.select2').select2({
                            minimumResultsForSearch: 15,
                            width: '100%',
                            placeholder: "Seleziona",
                            language: "it"
                        });
                    },
```

Comment: I didn't mean to add an answer, I just meant to say thank you, this saved me some time!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm happy that my solution was helpful to someone

Comment: Right now when I'm looking at https://sweetalert2.github.io/ v10.15.5 docs, onOpen is depreciated in favour of didOpen

Answer (score 5):

the above answer is work but if dropdown of select2 opened in under of swal2 alert use this CSS

```
    .select2-container--open {
    z-index: 99999999999999;
    }
```

Comment: Four 9s should be enough

Answer (score 3):

```
.select2-container--open {
z-index: 99999999999999;
}
```

That works better :)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.  To help others understand how that solves the issue, can you please [edit] your question and add an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the select2 dropdown container to the swal modal to fix some z-index and positioning issues.

```js
swal.fire({
    html: htmlContent,
    ...
    didOpen: function () {
        $("#swal2-html-container .select2").select2({
            ...
            dropdownParent: $('#swal2-html-container')
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach too, for the problem of the not seeing the dropdown list, especially if you don't want to define a CSS rule

```
   $('select[name=your_name]').on('select2:open', ()=>{
        $('.select2-container').css('z-index', 99999999);
    });
```